# MultipartParser is not validating data in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am using a `multipart/form-data`  in a form which have a manytomany relation as well as multiple file upload. But the validated data doesn't contains the array data

Views.py

```
class ExpenseCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = ( MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        owner = request.user.pk
        d = request.data.copy()
        d['owner'] = owner
        serializer = ExpenseSerializer(data=d)
        print("exp")

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializers.py

```
class ExpenseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    transactions = ExpenseTransactionsSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    bill = ExpenseFilesSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validated data", validated_data)
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('transactions', None)
        files_objects = validated_data.pop('bill', None)
        prdcts = []
        files = []
        for item in items_objects:
            i = ExpenseTransactions.objects.create(**item)
            prdcts.append(i)

        if files_objects == None:
            pass
        else:
            for item in files_objects:
                i = ExpenseFiles.objects.create(**item)
                files.append(i)

        instance = Expense.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.transactions.set(prdcts)
        instance.bill.set(files)
        return instance
```

How else should I use the MultiPartParser class in the views ?

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

at

```
for item in items_objects:
```

Comment: Please, show your ExpenseTransactionsSerializer

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `transactions` in validated_data. If transactions can empty or not required, just change:

```
validated_data.pop('transactions', None)
```

to

```
validated_data.pop('transactions', [])
```

It means that if transactions not in validated_data then pop `[]` (an empty list),  instead of `None`, then empty list can keep iterate in next your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try `validated_data.get` instead of `validated_data.pop`